# Given $f(x)$ with inverse $g$, find $g'(2)$

Tags: functions, logarithms, inverse

**Problem**

Given the function $$f(x) = \ln^3(x) - 2\ln^2(x) + \ln(x)$$ defined for $$x\in[e, e^3]$$ show that the function has an inverse $g$ on the given interval, and find $g'(2)$

**Progress**

I have concluded that $f$ has an inverse on the interval by showing that it is continuous and strictly increasing.

**Question**

How do I find $g'(2)$? I have contemplated trying to calculate the inverse of $f$ by hand, but given the wording of the problem, I don't think that's intended.

Can I find $g'(2)$ using some other neat trick?

Any help/solution appreciated!

Comment: There is a general formula for the derivative of the inverse of a function, do you know it?

Comment: @Did - Oooh! No! That sounds like it would solve all of my problems. I can obviously find this myself now that I know that such a thing exists, but if you'd like to post that as a hint in an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: You mean "Oooh! Yes!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

$g'(2)={1\over f'(x_0)}$, where $x_0$ is such that $f(x_0)=2$. Can you find it?

Comment: Yes! $x_0 = e^2$ seems to satisfy that equation. That gives me $$\displaystyle g'(2) = \frac{1}{f'(e^2)} = \frac15$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$$

That could help.